# Fastest way to iterate over a list and see if element exists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got two large lists I'm comparing, but my algorithm is *super* slow.

Is there a faster way to compare each element of the list?  Effectively, I want to find each URL where the id is present and parse out one segment of the URL.

The example below works, it just works *slow*.

```
# This list actually has ~100k elements
ids_as_string = ["123948", "123094", "123049", "123095"]

# This list actually has ~2.2 million elements
url_list = [
    "http://www.url.com/test/dont-find-me/id_123",
    "http://www.url.com/test/dont-find-this/id_124",
    "http://www.url.com/test/find-this/id_123948",
    "http://www.url.com/test/me-too/id_123094",
    "http://www.url.com/test/not-me/id_1235",
    "http://www.url.com/test/find-me-too/id_123049"
]

addresses = []
counter = 0
for id in ids_as_string:
    for url in url_list:
        if id in url:
            address = url.split("/")[4].replace("-", " ")
            counter += 1
            print(f"Appending {counter}")
            addresses.append(address)
            break
```

Comment: Are all of the ids numeric? Do they have length 6? Does each URL have exactly one id in it? Tell us as much as you can about the input format.

Comment: Good questions: 1) IDs are all numeric.  2) ID Length varies.  3) Each URL has exactly one ID in it.  4) Position of the ID and the string I'm finding don't change relative to ```/``` as separators.

Comment: Can the same id occur in two different urls?

Comment: @martineau No.  Each URL and id is unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current time complexity is ***O(NxM)***  where

*N = len(ids_as_string )

M = len(url_list )*

What you can do is, re-organise your data-structure in to maps

```
{id : url}
```

Example, process your 'id_123' into map, looking at your code, I assume id's are unique in URLs.
like

```
lookup_map = {
    '123' : "http://www.url.com/test/dont-find-me/id_123",
    '124' : "http://www.url.com/test/dont-find-this/id_124"
    <so on>
    }
```

To process this, time complexity is ***O(N)*** N is length of url list.

the just do

```
for id in ids_as_string:
   if id in lookup_map:
      <OK>
```

each *'if in'* look-up takes ***O(1)*** so, Total complexity: ***O(N) + O(M)***

Comment: I had made an error in the URL format posted - it was actually ```/123_id/```, but updating that, this answer works best.

Answer (score 1):

Turn one of your two lists into a `set` and then use the `in` operator for a fast O(1) lookup, turning your O(N*M) nested loop into a single O(N) `set` conversion and O(M) loop.

Note that this way your `if id in url` check does not work, but if the `id` is always in the same position you can extract it and then check whether it's in the set of IDs.

```
>>> id_set = set(ids_as_string)
>>> [url for url in url_list if url.split("_")[-1] in id_set]
['http://www.url.com/test/find-this/id_123948',
 'http://www.url.com/test/me-too/id_123094',
 'http://www.url.com/test/find-me-too/id_123049']
```